# Корректно ли выделена основа предложения в справочнике для подготовки к ОГЭ от ФИПИ?

Tags: тип-сказуемого, грамматическая-основа

В задании №2 есть предложение:

> В наше время слово "ошеломить" имеет значение "привести в состояние растерянности или даже потрясения".

Ответ №5, в котором основа пятого предложения представлена в виде "слово имеет значение", в справочнике указан как верный. Правильно ли это? Разве "имеет значение" является здесь полнозначным сочетанием?

Answer (score 1):

*Слово **имеет значение*** (= слово значит).

ПГС может выражаться глагольными фразеологизмами и **глагольно-именными** описательными оборотами, которые по смыслу эквивалентны глаголу: **оказать помощь** (помочь); **проявлять заботу** (заботиться).

**[Кустова Г. И. Синтаксис современного русского зыка](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)**, стр. 68.

Comment: Не могу согласиться с тем, что в данном случае "имеет значение" (=означает, значит) эквивалентно глаголу. Все приведенные примеры (мотать на ус, оказать помощь и т.д.) лексически полнозначны. Сочетание "имеет значение" будет таким только в следующем контексте: 1. Для меня это имело значение. 2. Число имеет большое значение. В нашем случае это сочетание похоже на связку "значит". В том же пособии Кустовой на стр. 73 приведен такой пример именной части в СИС: "9) инфинитив: Уйти значило признать свое поражение". Неужели ошибкой будет выделение такой основы: "слово имеет значение привести"?

Comment: Ну пусть будет:   иметь значение = значить. В наше время слово "ошеломить" имеет значение (= значит) "привести в состояние растерянности или даже потрясения". ЗНАЧИТЬ, -чу, -чишь; значащий; нсв. 1. что, с инф. или с придат. дополнит. Иметь какой-л. смысл, означать (о СЛОВАХ, знаках, жестах и т. п.). Имя Виктор значит победитель.  У Кустовой другое: Там говорится не о значении слова, а о значении действия в  конкретной ситуации, это действительно связочный вариант.

Comment: А у вас именно словарное значение. ОШЕЛОМИТЬ, -млю, -мишь; ошеломлённый; -лён, -лена, -лено; св. кого (что). 1. Привести в замешательство, растерянность своей неожиданностью.